# Django 1.3 get_absolute_url and localeurl

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-localeurl

I am using Django 1.3 in my project and switching away from the javascript i18n function to localeurl.

Really handy although I am stuck with my get_absolute_url().

Everytime I try and call up a page it defaults to the default language, even if I have selected another one.

is there a workaround for `get_absolute_url()` to incorprate the existing language code?

Comment: Have you tried changing language in the web-browser? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try whith this:

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language
get_language()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how/where to use this in relation to get_absolute_url?